# DateTime.TryParse returns unexpected value for month

Tags: c#

ParseExact method for Code A and Code B segements below is returning Month=1 not 12. Why? Note, no exceptions raised.  Thx.

```
        cult = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        //Code A
        //This code sets dt2=01/01/2009, with month = 01 not 12!
        cult = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact("2009-12-1", "yyyy-m-d", cult);
        printIt(dt2);

        //Code B
        //This code sets dt3=01/01/2009, with month = 01 not 12!
        DateTime dt3 = DateTime.ParseExact("2009-12-1", "yyyy'-'mm'-'d", cult);
        printIt(dt3);

        //Code C
        //This code works and sets dt4=12/01/2009
        DateTime dt4 = DateTime.Parse("2009-12-1",  cult);
        printIt(dt4);
```

Comment: This is trivially answered by looking at what the format strings actually mean. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lower case `m` is Minutes, you have to use `MM` instead

This for example works:

```
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact("2009-12-1", "yyyy-MM-d", cult);
```

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem about 7 years ago, I guess it was with Oracle then...